# unable to send c++ program with ajax call to php

Tags: javascript, php, c++, ajax

we have tried a lot of things to pass c++ code from a 'form' to php using ajax.basically text formatting is incorrect and characters are lost ,some newline characters and special characters are getting included in between,

we tried

1)encodeurlcomponent in javascript and rawurldecode in php

2)we tried encodeurlcomponent(code).replace(/!/g, '%21').replace(/'/g, '%27').replace(/(/g, 
'%28').replace(/)/g, '%29').replace(/*/g, '%2A')

we also tried various encoding schemes such as Utf-8,some 1so format

```
var code = $("#code").val();
$.ajax({
        url:"post.php",
        data:"code="+encodeURIComponent(code).replace(/!/g, '%21').replace(/'/g, '%27').replace(/\(/g, '%28').replace(/\)/g, '%29').replace(/\*/g, '%2A')    ,
        type:"post",
        success: function(result) {
         //something
         },
        error: function() {

            }
        }); 

php
$code = urldecode ($_POST['code']);
```

in php we are trying to decode the c++ program but some new lines are getting included in between

for Example

```
printf("%d %d\n",v,c);
```

this line becomes

```
printf("%d %d
\n",v,c);
```

after decoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure the code is being entered into a textarea.  Then use .html() to fetch the contents to prevent jQuery from doing extra work.

Then, pass an object to the data property of the ajax call.  jQuery and PHP should handle everything else for you.

html

```
<textarea id="code"></textarea>
```

js

```
var code = $("#code").html();
$.ajax({
        url:"post.php",
        data: {
            code: code
        },
        type:"post",
        success: function(result) {
            //something
        },
        error: function() {

        }
    });
```

php

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
```